# Is it possible to add more login options for Ethereum Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, feature-request, login

Ethereum StackExchange is mainly a developer community and most relevant projects are available on [Github](https://github.com). Github authentication [was added for StackOverflow in late 2019](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/11/announcing-support-for-github-authentication-in-stack-overflow/).

Would it be possible to get Github Authentication for Ethereum StackExchange, just like StackOverflow does?

[image: Login with GitHub (screenshot)]

Also, very specific to Ethereum - would it be possible to **additionally** get a **Log in with Ethereum** option that allows you to use the site with any Web3 provider such as Brave or [Metamask](https://www.toptal.com/ethereum/one-click-login-flows-a-metamask-tutorial)? That would be a feature very specific to Ethereum and might help faster onboarding for developers and enthusiasts that already use Ethereum. (See also [Serverless-Auth](https://github.com/austintgriffith/scaffold-eth/tree/serverless-auth).)

[image: login with metamask workflow]

See also: [The Ethereum community has accidentally solved a major problem of the Internet: Single Sign-On](https://twitter.com/BrantlyMillegan/status/1402388133086367751)

Comment: There's more than one question here.  Referencing the logo question here won't get it any additional views or answers.  Additionally, you could argue that the two suggestions for alternative logins should be separate questions.

Comment: Ok, I removed the reference. I haven't seen a CM or any Staff here for years, I thought if I get attention, I will point them accordingly. Do you want me to create two questions for the logins?

Comment: I wouldn't bother creating two, especially after your edit.