# Wen StackExchange token?

Tags: discussion

A lot of projects and individuals want to support people who contribute to the Ethereum ecosystem. Take for example airdrops where you can be eligible if you donate to Gitcoin Grants, NFTs for Github repo contributors, Reddit tokens (is that even a thing anymore?) or various POAPs.

What about supporting Ethereum StackExchange contributors?

I don't have any concrete proposal. Some random ideas:

- Token/NFT airdrop for contributors
- NFTs for contributors to be used as PFP (maybe even somehow related to the Christmas PFP swag we get)
- Possibility to gift/tip tokens (although this wouldn't be possible through the platform)
- Sell NFTs for valuable answers ("this NFT represents this answer, buy it to support it")

This doesn't have to be anything worth anything (although nobody knows what is valuable in 5 years), but something to show appreciation in Ethereum fashion.

Is this something that would be completely contrary to StackExchange ethos?

Comment: I endorse this idea

Comment: Upvoted. Maybe a starting point is [@q9f suggestion of a stackapp](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268/is-tipping-allowed-on-the-ethereum-stackexchange-site?rq=1#comment246_273) Or a stackapp could be avoided if people here add additional details to their profile, then a DApp with an oracle can read StackExchange profiles.

Comment: I've been suggesting this [since 2020](https://twitter.com/PaulRBerg/status/1280108454913413121).

Comment: Right, so how should we start? I have never figured out whether there's a possibility to chat with a group in StackExchange. I'm open to brainstorming this with any interested group/individual - if not here then my contact info is available in profile.

Comment: I have received zero messages regarding this so nobody is working on this. I'm still interested in working on this, but won't do it alone.

Comment: I asked for simple things like [GitHub authentication and Sign-in with Ethereum](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/681/is-it-possible-to-add-more-login-options-for-ethereum-stack-exchange) which is very reasonable in my opinion but never received a response. If you want this to go anywhere, I suggest giving it a more descriptive title for the start. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Personally I think it's a great idea however I can't stop the idea in my mind that suddenly there will be a overflow of hyped teens trying to farm the platform... Perhaps NFT would not fit this idea but stuff like "buy me a coffee" scheme with crypto or non transferrable nft tokens for contributions might do it just right

The value of stackexchange comes from the knowledge it holds and it's community of devs, I guess it will not hurt to have some short of "achievements Tokens"  here

A brief crazy idea:

Regarding UI, I guess we could just deploy an "Easter egg" contract with mint functions... With No UI.. ahah We're Sol Devs, we don't need UI to call contracts

Comment: Thanks for the ideas and engagement! I think there are a lot of things that could be thought of, and it probably shouldn't be something like "get 1 token for each 1 SE point". I wouldn't want this to be gamified, but that's a common problem with all community tokens.

Comment: I used the wrong term "gamification" I wanted to express "Achievement Tokens"; If it was on me, I'd give some NFT for good contributions or community hard jobs, I definitely agree that Achievements are supposed to be earned for real challenges... not farming